# Play Store : How to re-initiate Android TV review after updating app

Tags: google-play-console, android-tv

I published an Android TV app in the play store. I opted in for the Android TV by visiting `Setup > Advanced Settings > Release Types`. It was later rejected for valid reasons and I received an email.

Now, I fixed the issues and published a new version.

I was expecting the `Rejected` status to change to `In Review` in the Android TV section in Advanced Settings.

But, sadly, it just shows `Update rejected`. It is not clear, if it means the new update is rejected. I did not get any email. Even the error message in the "Policy" section only shows the last rejection details and date also reflects the first rejection.

Now, I think, the review is not even initiated after publishing the update. How can I initiate the review? I tried `opt-out ⇨ save ⇨ opt-in`. Even then, it does not go to `in review` status.

Any help is appreciated...

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Note that the newer version of the app is approved as a regular app. The reject is only on the `Android TV`.

[image]

Comment: Facing the same issue. did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I think their UI does not reflect that it is being reviewed again. The app was reviewed and rejected again in my case after few days. So, you might want to wait for few days.

Comment: facing same issue, same to same... how to resolve?

Comment: I think their UI does not reflect that it is being reviewed again. The app was reviewed and rejected again in my case after few days. So, you might want to wait for few days.

Comment: Having the same problem - any progress on this? What should I do? I've been waiting for 2 days and nothing.